# Getting error while deployment of Python Script to Azure Function App via VSCode because of missing packages but they are present in environment

Tags: azure, visual-studio-code, azure-functions, python-3.11

Getting error while deploying the local Python workspace in VSCode to Azure Function App because of missing packages. The package outlined by VSCode as missing are actually present in environment. The local environment contains the Azure packages but in VSCode they are not recognized. As the Azure packages are not recognized the debugging is throwing an error and consecutively the deployment is not happening.

[image: VSCode Screen shot]

[image: Conda Environemt Package List]

[image: Azure Screenshot 1]

[image: Azure Screenshot 4]

Please help.

Initially there was a python version mismatch between 3.10 on the local and 3.11 on Azure. On Python 3.10 the Azure packages were installed and the deployment was working out but after deployment the was a runtime error. When I fixed the python version mismatch and had both the systems running 3.11 the azure packages started creating the problem.

Please suggest the correct path t fix these errors.

Thanks

Comment: Please provide your function code in text format

Answer (score 0):

> The local environment contains the Azure packages but in VS Code they are not recognized. As the Azure packages are not recognized the debugging is throwing an error and consecutively the deployment is not happening.

In order to resolve this error, you need to add the packages in **requirement.txt**.

**requirement.txt**-

```py
azure-functions
azure-identity
azure-storage-blob
```

****init**.py**-

```py
import datetime
import logging

import azure.functions as func
from azure.identity import DefaultAzureCredential
from azure.storage.blob import BlobServiceClient, BlobClient, ContainerClient


def main(mytimer: func.TimerRequest) -> None:
    utc_timestamp = datetime.datetime.utcnow().replace(
        tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc).isoformat()

    if mytimer.past_due:
        logging.info('The timer is past due!')

    logging.info('Python timer trigger function ran at %s', utc_timestamp)
```

I am getting the expected output while debugging the function.

[image]

After deployment, I am getting the successful response as well.

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much. After your suggestion the deployment was successful. But I have run into another error. The script that I have written is given below. I am trying to create a series of text files on the connected Blog Storage. I am unable to trace out the error. It would be great if you can help me.

Comment: Here is the link to the code that I have written::

https://docs.google.com/document/d/13z4_rgl_oURFps_fNYrRStI3qtLyycnDSkUfT6HgZF4/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: @SChakrabarti can you share the error message

Comment: @SChakrabarti please share your code in text format